# Access - Form to control meeting minutes

Tags: forms, ms-access, text, textbox, field

I'm creating a form to control meeting minutes, including participants, date, topic, and actions.

There will be some updates and reviews to the actions decided, and I have a text box linked to a field where I input these actions.

However, when the fields are updated, I want to add the new actions to the prior ones but prevent people from editing prior actions, so basically it will be always adding new info to the field.

I thought about creating a temporary field or concatenate functions, but at the end none of them really worked. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Upon configuring an appropriate table of your meetings, wherein each record uniquely identifies a single meeting via an appropriate primary key, you could then construct a separate table or multiples tables to house the updates, reviews, actions applicable to each meeting.

In this way, each record within the *updates* table could contain a foreign key uniquely identifying the meeting to which it applies, a foreign key to a *users* table referencing the user whom entered the update, and a datetime stamp, amongst other relevant fields.

This way, updates/reviews/actions are added as distinct records (with explicit control over deletions) and there is an inherent transaction log which may be audited if necessary.